# how to use thread to capture screen after scrolling in UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form which hold a web browser control, that web browser will change it's position automatically in fixed positions

So first I set the navigate to position X then I will take a capture from my form then change the position to Y and also take another capture.

My Issue is that I use the navigation to position like

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:window.scroll(0," + X + ");");
```

So I should wait tell the ui change the position then Do the capture code, after finish I should re-change the position to Y same way and wait tell the UI finish then capture.

I try to use background worker but it didn't support me as well I also try Threading but as I;m not so good dealing with Threading my ui didn't navigate before capture.
I use Threading like:

```
ThreadStart captureFunc = new ThreadStart(CaptureScreen);
Thread captureThread = new Thread(captureFunc);
captureThread.Start();
while (!doneVal)
{

}
captureThread.Abort();
```

while `CaptureScreen` is my capture function and `doneVal` is a value with default false and changed to true after capture.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use synchronization-primitives such as `Mutex`, `Events`, and `WaitHandles`. You should never infinite-loop to create a "synchronization".

Comment: I'm not as well using thread but I'm reading about it now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser`-control offers `Events`, such as the [`Navigated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx)-Event.
You can use this to determine the end of the navigation of the `WebBrowser`-control:

```
webBrowser1.Navigated += NavigatedEventHandler; //use in constructor for example

...

private void NavigatedEventHandler(object sender, NavigatedEventArgs e){

    //perform actions here

}
```

Comment: This event occurred only when navigate the URL it self my navigation is something like execute javascript function to scroll so it won't occur when just scrolling, Thank you